# How to add div's within my div's that change with my slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the current code and I am trying to put tabs on the side of my slideshow that change as the images change. and so the current image we are at is shown by the tab the active tab while still displaying the other tabs but in another color. The attached code is what I have come up with so far, but I can't seem to understand what comes next. I also tried to have my text vertical. I am also having trouble changing the height parameter of the tab div's, I changed the html but they wont get taller.

I just started learning I hope some one can help me out. Thanks.

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div id="content_transparent"> 
    <div id="slideshow">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div id="barChart_div" style="width: 60px; height: 50px;float:left;background-color: blue;"><p class="css-vertical-text">tab1</p></div>
                <div id="stats_div" style="width: 60px; height: 50px; float:left;background-color: green; margin-top:50px;margin-left:-60px">tab2</div>
                <div id="lineChart_div" style="clear:left; width: 60px; height: 50px;background-color: red;">tab3</div>
                <div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 60px; height: 50px;background-color: orange;">tab4</div>
            </div>
            <div class="fadein">
                <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"></div>
                <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg"></div>
                <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here's my css:

```css
p.css-vertical-text {
    writing-mode:tb-rl;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    white-space:nowrap;
    display:block;
    bottom:0;
    font-family:‘Trebuchet MS’, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:24px;
    font-weight:normal;
}

.fadein {
    position:relative;
    height:572px;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}

.fadein img {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:95%;
    height:572px;
    left:60px;
}

.fadein div {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

#content_transparent {
    z-index:2;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border:3px solid black;
    height:1600px;
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;
    margin-top:30px;
}

#slideshow{
    width:100%;
    height:575px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for [jQuery Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default).

It offers easy to use tab-functionality and is used to following way:

1) You include the jQuery and jQuery UI javascripts in your HTML document and include the jQuery UI CSS file

2) You define the tabs and their content as follows

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"></div>
  <div id="tabs-2"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"></div>
  <div id="tabs-3"><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

3) You create a javascript block to initiate the tabbing functionality as follows

```
<script>
    $(function() {
       $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
    });
</script>
```

4) That's it.

Comment: Hi, this is quite an interresting way to look at it. However, I was more looking to recreate something that looks like this: [link](http://www.thenorthface.com/en_CA/index.html).

Comment: Ah okay! Then you might want to take a look at the jQuery Cycle Plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html. Especially at the "Pager" functionality. You can build something shown in your link in minutes with this :)

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Could you point me in the right direction as to how to combine the pager exemple with the exemple right next to it (manuel and auto advance) as to automate the slideshow.